# Read binary values from a dataset without removing the leading zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset something like this:

```
0000000000000001,0
0000000000000010,0
0000000000000011,0
0000000000000100,0
.
.
.
1110110101101110,0
1111010110111000,0
```

I want to read the **first column** of each row. The following code does that **but** removes the leading zeros! it prints something link this:

```
1
10
11
100
.
.
.
```

How can I keep the leading zeros? I tried `format(i[0], '#016b')` but it does not produce the same values in the dataset.

```
import numpy as np

my_data = np.genfromtxt('2_223A5.csv', delimiter=',')
for i in my_data:
    print(int(i[0])) # this removes the leading zeros!
```

Comment: You should not convert the binary to an `int`.

Comment: `np.genfromtxt('2_223A5.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='str')[:,0]`

Comment: well, if you wrote a number with bunch if 0s at the beginning would it make sense? *int* is just a number, if you want another representation then you have to specify it

Answer (score 0):

The solution (solved in comments) is to read in your data as strings. Specify a `dtype` to the function:

```
np.genfromtxt('2_223A5.csv', delimiter=',', dtype='str')[:,0]
```

Use `[:,0]` to slice out the first column, which was what you wanted.